# "Back" button on Navigation Bar is disabled after view push

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am pushing a view controller (`DetailView`) via my table view's delegate class, `MyClass`.
`MyClass` acts as a delegate for a table view in `MasterView`. Im attempting to push `DetailView` from the "didSelectRowAtIndexPath:" method of `MyClass` but every time `DetailView` is pushed the back button leading back to `MasterView` is disabled.

My Code for pushing the view:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

if (!detailViewController) {
    detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
}

AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDelegate.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `[appDelegate.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];`, use `[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];`.

It sounds like the `appDelegate`'s nav controller is a different instance to the `MasterView`'s one, which would explain the weird behaviour.

Using `self.navigationController` pushes another view controller on top of the `MasterView` nav controller's stack.

Comment: This is coming from MyClass because MyClass doesn't have an inherited navigation controller

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to get your push call back to your MasterView.

You can either do this by setting a protocol in MyClass and firing the push call back through the delegate from MyClass to MasterView (which makes for a strange back and forth delegation pattern), using the notification center (might be useful if multiple views need to know this push is happening), or by passing in a reference to the MasterView when you initialize MyClass and use that for the push.

No matter what you choose, trying to use the AppDelegate's nav controller will definitely give you strange results.

Comment: Are you sending the NSNotification from MyClass and then listening to it in MasterView? When you get the notification it should post like Vinny's comment below in the MasterView class. `[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES]`

Comment: Yes. When the notification is caught by MasterView another method is called that pushes the view exactly like that.

Comment: I have actually noticed this happens when any ViewController is being pushed from MasterView

Comment: Starting to sound like something is up with your MasterView...Assuming MasterView is the first view for your app, the root view from your app delegate should be the navigation controller containing MasterView. It's tough to tell the problem at this point, but I don't think it's the push itself for sure.